# Prove every nonzero ordinal is either successor or limit

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

I am trying to prove the statement in the title.

Here is my partial proof:

> Let $n$ be a nonzero ordinal. It is obvious that $\cup_{\beta<n}\beta \subseteq n$.
>
> If $\cup_{\beta<n}\beta = n$, then $n$ is a limit ordinal
>
> Otherwise, $\cup_{\beta<n}\beta \subsetneq n$. Then $\exists\,\alpha\in n\;(\alpha\notin\cup_{\beta<n}\beta)$. It follows that $\forall\beta<n\;(\alpha\ge\beta)$

The only thing left to prove is that $n = \alpha\cup\{\alpha\}$, which I can't figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:** Show that $\alpha$ is the only ordinal in $n$ which is not an element of the union $\bigcup n$.

Comment: Yes it follows directly from $\forall\beta<n\;(n>a\ge\beta)$. But how to prove $\alpha = \cup n$ without assuming $\alpha$ is a successor ordinal?

Comment: Well, suppose it wasn't. Then there is some $\gamma<\alpha$ such that $\gamma\notin\bigcup n$. But what does it mean $\gamma<\alpha$ in terms of $\in$? Find a contradiction, and you're done.

Comment: Got it. Thanks.